# window getting close after print,i want to stop the close event

Tags: javascript, html, printing

I want to stop the close event of the window which is invoking the print event after printing is finished. can anyone help?

codes below:

```
w = window.open();
w.document.write("Name:");
w.document.write(CPNtext);
w.document.write("\t");
w.document.write("<br/>");
w.document.write("Address:");
w.document.write(Destinationaddress);
w.focus();
w.print();w.close();
```

Comment: I'm not sure this closes that window. I tried it [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w24sm58p/). I deleted those variables because I don't know what's stored in them. They don't matter here.

Comment: Hello Marfee, thanks for putting your time in this. Actually, these codes run on button click which opens a new webpage on a new tab with the data to be printed. So, as I save or print the data, the window or tab closes and it also closes the window in which the button is coded. And i forgot to add "w.close()" in the end, which I have just edited. This time the codes will surely close both the windows. and I want to prevent the window having button which is calling these codes.